# jQuery XML Parse - check if Element has attribute

Tags: jquery, xml

Would you please help with an issue i have with some XML documents.

When parsing through the documents I am getting to a point where i need to only acquire the pertinent data.

Here is an example of a set of child elements that I am looping:

```
<element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
<text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
<text type="probability_of_precipitation">10%</text>

$(locationInfo).children().each(function(){
alert($(this).attr("forecast_icon_code"));
});
```

The returned value is "undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do like:

```
var attr = $(this).attr("forecast_icon_code");
if (typeof attr !== 'undefined') {
    ..do something with it
}
```

or

```
if ($(this).is('[forecast_icon_code]')) {
    ..have the attribute
}
```

Comment: beautifully simple and on the money. With this I used, the $(this).text() to get the value of the element based on the attr, niceone!